# Why can't we call asList() on an array reference directly?

Tags: arrays, string, list, methods, collections

I have a rather weird question but I thought it's better to clarify then just follow by the book I'm reading currently.

Right now, I'm learning about `Collections` and how to convert arrays into a `List`.

For e.g,

```
String[] colors = {"red", "blue", green", "white", "orange"};
List<String> list = Arrays.asList(colors);
```

My question is why can't we just directly invoke the method?

```
String[] colors = {"red", "blue", green", "white", "orange"};
colors.asList();
```

Whereas for the `String` class, we can convert a string object to say uppercase directly by invoking the method?

```
String[] colors = {"red", "blue", green", "white", "orange"};
String result = colors.toUpperCase();
```

Comment: No. `colors.toUpperCase();` won't compile either.

Comment: Array class was designed a long ago and many static methods should have been instance methods but too late to change this as it will break millions of line of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is why can't we just directly invoke the method?

You can't invoke the method because the method is not present in any of the array type classes. You can't call a method that is not defined in a class. For example :

```
class MyClass {
   public void method() { }
}
```

You can't say `new MyClass().whyCantICallThisMethod()` because `MyClass` doesn't have this method.

That said, arrays are different from other classes as they are created by the JVM (at runtime). The designers did not see it fit to ask the JVM to dynamically add the `asList` method.

Comment: I see. So when we create an array, it's known to be a type class? it doesn't actually link to the array class library?

Comment: @Scorpiorian83 If you are asking whether `Array` class is linked to `String[]` or `int[]` or any other array type, the answer is no again. `Array` is class containing utility methods and is different from the class objects created for `String[]` or `int[]` or any other array type.

Answer (score 0):

Static methods are invoked using class name and instance methods are invoked on instance. `asList()` is defined as static method in `Arrays` class, therefore you don't need to create an instance of `Arrays` class. Instead you invoke it as `<Class-Name>.<Static-Method>` which in your case is `Arrays.asList()`.

Therefore, in your example code, for `String[] colors` array you can't invoke `asList()` method.

Also, `toUpperCase()` method will not work on an array of string, rather you can invoke that on `String` object.